# What does this part "might equally well have done" mean?

Tags: grammar

What does the part "might equally well have done" mean?

> Several have defined man as an animal which laughs. They **might equally well have defined** him as an animal which is laughed at. [Source](http://books.google.co.jp/books?id=jeh9WiRIdW0C&pg=PA10&dq=%E2%80%9CThe%20comic%20does%20not%20exist%20outside%20the%20pale%20of%20what%20is%20strictly%20human...%20Laughter%20has%20no%20greater%20foe%20than%20emotion.&hl=en&sa=X&ei=BobHUrDgKcXXkgX7koCACg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=laughter%20of%20a%20group&f=false)

I can't find this in my dictionary.

Comment: They `might (just) as well have defined` him as an animal which is laughed at. "might (just) as well" is a well-known idiom and the phrase in question looks like a variation of this idiom.

Answer (score 1):

**Might equally well have ** is not a set phrase and you will not find it in a dictionary. You have to parse it in order to understand.

They **have defined** → that's present perfect of *define*.

They **might** have defined → *might* is used here to say that it was possible but they did not do it.

**Equally well** are both adverbs that form a group that modifies the verb and means here "in an equal manner".

I understand the complete sentence as meaning that those who defined man as an animal which laughs could have defined him in the same manner as an animal which is laughed at.

Answer (score 0):

It is the author's opinion that the two definitions ("animal who laughs" and "animal who is laughed at") are equally appropriate and valid.